# The property can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, api, dart

Hi I'm having two problems when trying to import API's into flutter, first it seems it seems it is unable to read the data from my snapshot so when I use the function if (snapshot.hasData) it keeps showing the CircularProgressIndicator.

Second problem is when I try to add a variables to allow me to add text from the API it is giving me the error 'The property can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null''`

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold (
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('News App'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<Welcome>(
          future: _Welcome,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 52,
                itemBuilder:(context, index) {
              var ticker = snapshot.data.ticker; //error here
              return Container(
                height: 100,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(ticker)
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
            } 
            else 
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
          
        ),
      )
    );
  }`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first problem try it with

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
```

For your second problem try adding an exclamation mark to guarantee the value is not null

```
var ticker = snapshot.data!.ticker;
```

Comment: For the first one it's now giving me another error. "The static getter 'done' can't be accessed through an instance."                                                                                                                           The second one worked! thanks.

Comment: Ah yep sorry I tried to edit the post. Can you try it again like this?