# The property 'snapshot' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

i was trying to connect my firebase with my flutter app but got the error

> "The property 'snapshot' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'." and
> "The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
> Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')"

it has an error in

```
snapshot.data.snapshot.value["Temperature:"]
```

and

```
snapshot.data.snapshot.value["Humidity:"]
```

My full code:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class IOTScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const IOTScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _IOTScreenState createState() => _IOTScreenState();
}

class _IOTScreenState extends State<IOTScreen> {
  bool value = false;
  bool values = false;
  final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeFirebase();
  }

  void initializeFirebase() async {
    try {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      print('Firebase initialized successfully');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to initialize Firebase: $e');
    }
  }

  void onUpdate() {
    setState(() {
      value = !value;
    });
  }

  void onUpdate2() {
    setState(() {
      values = !values;
    });
  }

  void writeData() {
    dbRef.child("Data").set({"Humidity: ": 0, "Temperature: ": 0});
    dbRef.child("LightStates").set({"switch": !value});
  }

  void writeData2() {
    dbRef.child("FanStates").set({"switch": !values});
  }

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
  return Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: dbRef.child("Data").onValue,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData &&
            !snapshot.hasError &&
            snapshot.data?.snapshot.value! != null) {
          return Column(
            children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.clear_all, size: 30),
                        Text(
                          "Egg Incubator",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Icon(Icons.settings, size: 30)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Temperature",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              snapshot.data.snapshot.value["Temperature:"],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Humidity",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          snapshot.data.snapshot.value["Humidity:"],
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 60,
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton.extended(
                      onPressed: () {
                        writeData();
                        onUpdate();
                      },
                      label: value ? Text("Lamp ON") : Text("Lamp OFF"),
                      elevation: 20,
                      backgroundColor: value ? Colors.yellow : Colors.white60,
                      icon: value
                          ? Icon(Icons.wb_incandescent)
                          : Icon(Icons.wb_incandescent_outlined)),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 60,
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton.extended(
                    onPressed: () {
                      onUpdate2();
                      writeData2();
                    },
                    label: values ? Text("Fan OFF") : Text("Fan ON"),
                    elevation: 20,
                    backgroundColor:
                        values ? Colors.white60 : Colors.blueAccent,
                    icon: values
                        ? Icon(Icons.wind_power_rounded)
                        : Icon(Icons.wind_power_outlined),
                  )
                ],
          );
        } else 
         return Container();
      },
    ),
  );
}
}
```

please let me know if you need any explanation. thankyou

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66670247/10157127) answer your question?
 
try like `snapshot.data?.snapshot.value?["Temperature:"]??"got null"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The property can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70865796/the-property-cant-be-unconditionally-accessed-because-the-receiver-can-be-null)

Comment: its fixed the probelm in "value" but there's still error line in "[]" says The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'